# Symbolic Link Restores Original File

Tags: symlink

On Linux, I created a file (file1):

```
echo Hello file1 > file1
```

Then, I created a symbolic link (file2), to file1:

```
ln -s file1 file2
```

After that, I removed file1:

```
rm file1
```

Lastly, I edited file2 to be different:

```
echo Changed file2 > file2
```

After all of these steps were executed, I observed that file1 and file2 now contain "Changed file2".

From what I understand, after file1 is removed, the symbolic link (file2) no longer works. However, the interesting part which I hope to get an answer to, is that editing file2 causes file1 to be restored (despite file1 being removed earlier on).

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4):

The first file, `file1`, was not actually restored by your process. It was instead created when you ran `echo Changed file2 > file2`. `file2` was a link to a then-non-existent file `file1`; a symlink does not have to point to an existing file. Because it was a symlink, the system resolved it and redirected the output of the `echo` command to `file1`, creating that file, and leaving the `file2` symlink in place pointing to `file1`.